# Is 节列俄阿木 a name?

Tags: names

In Xi Jinping's 2018/2019 New Year [Address](http://language.chinadaily.com.cn/a/201901/01/WS5c2ad70aa310d91214051e48.html) there is this phrase:
我看望了彝族村民吉好也求、节列俄阿木两家人

The official (?) [translation](http://language.chinadaily.com.cn/a/201901/01/WS5c2ad70aa310d91214051e48.html) is only vague:
"I visited the families of two villagers from the Yi people"

I wonder about what a close translation would look like. Judging from news reports, I take it that 吉好也求 is a name. Also 节列俄阿木 [seems](http://www.cac.gov.cn/2019-01/04/c_1123946182.htm) to be a name. Is it? Or does it refer to a "Russian(-Afghan?) section"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a name. It is a name of a man of Yi nationality, so it is different from most Chinese names (those of Han nationality).

Answer (score 0):

吉好也求

节列俄阿木

是中国少数民族 彝族 的姓名
(this is "Yi National" of the Chinese minority name)